HTML Elements in Laravel
Currently I am pulling product information & HTML elements from the database, I have used {!! !!} to display unescaped data.
This works on web browsers, however in the ios & android application it still brings in all the html code.
Below is the line of code:
`
<tr>
<th>Product Overview</th>
<td>
@if(isset($product->product_overview) || count($product->product_overview) > 0)
<ul>
@foreach($product->product_overview as $value)
<li>
<h5>{{$value['title']}}</h5>
<p>{!! $value['description'] !!}</p>
</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@endif
</td>
</tr>
`

Is there any other code I should be using?
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/kEYmNMfb.png)

"however in the ios & android application" - If this is a separate Swift/Java (or React Native, etc.) app, then {!! ... !!} wouldn't apply, as that is PHP code via Blade Templating. If you're viewing the webpage on your phone (i.e. responsive layout), then it should be the same. You might need to edit your question and provide some clarification, especially if you're using a separate codebase for your iOS/Android App.

If you are using the same codebase for serving a webapp and a native mobile app, then, first:

You'll need API endpoints for the mobile Apps;
You'll need WEB endpoints for the web version.

On the web, you'll use templates to render.
On the API, you'll only send data; and you'll have to use native elements to render with that data (if using Swift or Java) - or if on React Native - use the proper elements. They are very similar to the HTML, but mainly, you'll just pass in data and make the Client app render it, with their own elements.
